# Having my reply deleted which EXACTLY anwered a quesion

Tags: discussion

The misreading of a question has caused this confusion.

[Does Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 have a fullscreen mode?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10494/does-adobe-premiere-pro-cs6-have-a-fullscreen-mode)
"Does Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 have a fullscreen mode?"
...
"I want to get rid of the Windows taskbar and the window border. The same way that you would go fullscreen with a browser by pressing F11."

If you press CTRL+'~' it operates EXACTLY the same way as hitting the F11 key on the browser.

Originally I mentioned only the '~' key, but that maintained the panel buttons and controls. But pressing CTRL+'~' fixes that.

I would like the answer that I provided to be undeleted because it was the CORRECT answer to that question. I can provide additional supporting documents, videos to support this assertion.

I don't believe the moderator should have deleted the post with trying the solution first.

Comment: Ah, I discovered part of the problem.  I should have re-read the question too.  The details he gave about specifically what he was looking for were actually from his comments on my answer, not the original question (which was a little bit ambiguous).  I have updated the question to reflect the comments he left on my answer so that it is more clear in the future.

Comment: Oh, as a side note, I wanted to apologize for the less than stellar experience.  I was actually at dinner when most of this was going down (I confirmed the behavior of ~ and ctrl-~ prior to going to dinner because someone else made a similar error before you.) so didn't get back to be able to really write out a fully explained response until I got home.

Comment: No, you are right, I misread the question. I thought he wanted to hide the OS taskbar which the CTRL+tilde did. Not realizing he wanted to have the Application full screen without the OS taskbar visible. I am unsure about CC as well, though I last read they were trying to make all the controls consistent across all their products, so it may well be possible, but I would not know since I use CS6

Comment: I know my method of response comes across harshly. Its just the way I am. I mean no disrespect by it. I sometimes scan questions when I need to thoroughly re-read them.

Comment: no problem, you're a great help around the site and I'm glad you're here.  I'm also super glad we got it worked out, cause I'd hate to see you leave.  We all have our faults.  I'm willing to put up with yours if you can put up with mine. :)  And yeah, would be nice if they'd update Premiere to have that feature set.  I would love it.  I use it all the time in Lightroom, though I have a high enough resolution monitor it isn't a huge problem.

Comment: btw, do you mind if I clean up the comment threads a bit on the question now that we have it worked out?  Let me know if you have any other concerns.

Comment: After letting it lay for a bit I think I have a better idea of how best to approach this in the future. I think its best to leave in answers that may have misunderstood the question, and just leave a note saying this is not the answer the OP was looking for because in the future when people search on this question quite a few would be thinking this is the solution. I remember I was not the only one to do that answer. The only time the answer should be removed if it grossly misunderstands the question, what do you think?

Comment: Hmm. I think it is an interesting idea that is probably worth a meta question of its own. The trick would probably be coming up with a clear definition of the line. I would love to know the community's thoughts on it though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this to meta.  I am wondering if perhaps this comes from a version difference issue.  The original question is asking about Premiere CS6.  Both ProfessorFartSparkle and I verified independently that CS6 does the full screen preview which is not what the user was asking for.  It may be that CC has changed that behavior.  I do think that it would be a legit answer to the question to explain that it is not possible in CS6, but is possible in CC though.  If you'd like, we can also discuss this more in chat (or here if you prefer) as it seems like a lot of the issues may just be based around misunderstandings.  I do very much want to see the issue resolved to everyone's satisfaction.

It also seems that part of the problem may be that the original question had been clarified in the comments to my answer and I was working off of memory of the question and didn't realize that the details from the comment never made it back in to the original question.  Given that, I do now think that your question did answer the question as it had been originally stated, so if you still want it undeleted I would be happy to do so for you, but the clarification in the comments on my answer (which I have since moved up in to the original question) do make your answer specifically not applicable (and still the full screen preview that the original question had said wasn't what was being looked for.)

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood his question a bit. Please don't see that as an insult to you or your answer.
The issue is that all he wants is get rid of the window control bar for maximizing and minimizing and the taskbar in Windows and explicitly said that he doesn't want a single panel or the preview to be in fullscreen, which is what you answered. He wants the same thing that Photoshop does when using the "Fullscreen Mode with Menu Bar" option under "View"->"Screen Mode".

Because he explicitly stated what he doesn't want, your answer isn't answering his question which under the guidelines should then be deleted.